# Java Layout help needed, MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

How to set the layout of adding a button to start from the center of the panel.
While adding another 1 will be below the first button.

as shown in the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxJG.jpg

Comment: Wish I knew `MigLayout`, but why not just supplied layouts with the framework !!! What you can do, is simply create a `JPanel` say `buttonPanel` having `GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5)` now add `JButton`s to this `buttonPanel`. Once done, add this `buttonPanel` to another `JPanel` say `contentPane` with `GridBagLayout()`, like `contentPane.add(buttonPanel)` with no constraints defined. This will put that in the middle, with no hassle :-)

Comment: my code are filled with this api already, doesnt want to redesign again hehe..thx i manage to fix myself